# curvycorners image inside div issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, curvycorners

I am using jquery curvy corners. I know another plugin named jquery corner is available, however it's file size being massively bigger than curvy corners, I decided to with curvy corners.

I have a markup like:

```
<div class="roundedBox" style="border-width: 4px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;
margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; border: solid 4px #008FD9;">
    <asp:Image Width="140"  ID="innerImg" runat="server" style="overflow:hidden;" />
</div>
```

and then in js I do:

```
 curvyCorners.addEvent(window, 'load', initCorners);
        function initCorners() {
              var settings = {
              tl: { radius: 20 },
              tr: { radius: 20 },
              bl: { radius: 20 },
              br: { radius: 20 },
              antiAlias: true
             };
             curvyCorners(settings, ".roundedBox");
         }
```

Problem is my image is overlapped on top of div and looks very ugly. How can I resolve this?

Attached is the image which shows the problem:

[image]

Comment: Try recreating this in a jsFiddle, or link us to a test page.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how the plugin works but it seems you need to apply the same styling to the image as you did the div.

**Only make the radius 16 though to account for the image border.**

Comment: Did it make any affect at all? It definitely works because there is an example on the Curvy Corners website that shows it working with images.

Comment: The examples on curvy corners website use a trick i.e they set the background of the div which is why you don't see image overlapped outside div. However I have a separate image inside div and I don't want to set background on my div.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `overflow:hidden` in your `.roundedBox` CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with curvy corners, but my instinct says this is a [z-index](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/) issue.

Comment: No, this is not a z-index issue. Changing z-index doesn't help.

Comment: Which browser?  We really need more data to go on.

Comment: Firefox 4, IE9, Chrome 14.0.835.202. Does that help?

Comment: It rules out IE7. =D  I'm not sure how the border is generated; is it an image, a colored div, css3, etc?  Really need to see a live sample.

Answer (score 0):

curvyCorners does not support image element:

elements cannot be rounded using curvyCorners. Instead, use a  element and set the image as the background-image of the .

[curvyCorners](http://www.curvycorners.net/instructions/)

I've a lot of issues with this plugin myself, and I had to get rid of it completely, I used malsup round corners instead.